# vba efficient loop to compare and do copy and paste for more than 10,000 values

Tags: vba, loops, coding-efficiency

I'd like to compare 2 time values and if they match, then paste the temperature value at that time, if there is one measurement missing at a particular point in time, then assign 0. This code currently works for 1000 values (takes less than 1 min), however for 10,000 values is takes more than an hour. How could the looping time be reduced?

```
Sub findMatching()
Dim CurrentLine As Integer, CurrentLine2 As Integer, CurrentLine3 As Integer
Dim MaxRows As Integer, MaxRows2 As Integer

MaxRows = 1000
MaxRows2 = 1000
CurrentLine = 1
For CurrentLine = 1 To MaxRows '-- Loop in A column (read data)
    For CurrentLine2 = 1 To MaxRows2 '-- Loop in D column (compare data)
      If Sheets(1).Cells(CurrentLine, 1) = Sheets(1).Cells(CurrentLine2,4) Then
      '-- copying matching data
    Sheets(1).Cells(CurrentLine, 2) = Sheets(1).Cells(CurrentLine2, 5)
    CurrentLine = CurrentLine + 1
    ElseIf Sheets(1).Cells(CurrentLine, 1) <> Sheets(1).Cells(CurrentLine2,4) Then
      Sheets(1).Cells(CurrentLine, 2) = 0
    End If
   Next CurrentLine2
 Next CurrentLine
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) For one thing, don't use all these cell accesses. Read the range into a VBA array in 1 line of code, modify the array, then push it back. 2) Use 2 loops and a dictionary rather than a nested loop. Load the dictionary in the first loop and then use it in the second.

Comment: I'd start by pulling it into an array, but the nested loop is what is killing you (1 million iterations with 1000 rows). With 10000 rows it would be 100 million iterations. I'm thinking vlookups would be much more efficient.

Comment: @JohnColeman I am at beginners stage with loops, could you please give me a code example? thanks

Comment: @Comintern I'll try it in a macro

Comment: @Comintern I tried this but it appears a message that there is not sufficient space in the memory:                                                       
 `Sub match()
Dim currentline As Long
currentline = 1
Rows = 2
For currentline = 1 To Rows
Sheets(1).Cells(currentline, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets(1).Cells(currentline, 1), Sheets(1).Range("D1:E8760"), 2, False)
Next currentline
End Sub`

Comment: Why the line `CurrentLine = CurrentLine + 1`? This is inside a for loop, where `CurrentLine` is automatically incremented. Incrementing it within the loop will cause the loop to sometimes skip over cells, perhaps many cells if a given value in column A is equal to multiple values in column D.

Comment: @JohnColeman I have 2 different arrays, one that contains each time value of the year 2017 per hour (2017010101, read as yyyymmddhr), and another time array which doesnt contain all hourly values (e.g. 2017010101, then insteadof 2017010102 -it jumps to 2017010105). In my solution, the temperature values at 2017010103 and 2017010104 should be cero values or #NA. so far I understand now arrays still I'd like to know what is "pushing it back" or "dictionary"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below relies on you being able to access the Scripting.Dictionary object. I use late binding, so you shouldn't need to add a reference.

You said that `Range.Resize` is killing you. Not too sure why that is, but I use it again in the code below. If you have performance issues, let me know.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub findFirstMatching()

    ' Declared two constants because OP had done it that way in their post.
    ' Depending on use case, could get rid of second and just use the one
    ' But having two allows you to change one without the other.
    Const READ_ROW_COUNT As Long = 10000 ' Used for columns A, B
    Const COMPARISON_ROW_COUNT As Long = 10000 ' Used for columns D, E

    ' Change sheet name below to wherever the data is. I assume Sheet1 '
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Dim columnA() As Variant
        columnA = .Range("A1").Resize(READ_ROW_COUNT, 1).Value2

        Dim columnD() As Variant
        columnD = .Range("D1").Resize(COMPARISON_ROW_COUNT, 1).Value2

        Dim columnE() As Variant
        columnE = .Range("E1").Resize(COMPARISON_ROW_COUNT, 1).Value2

        Dim dict As Object
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        Dim rowIndex As Long

        ' Fill dictionary (array values as dictionary's keys, row numbers as dictionary's corresponding values)
        ' If there are duplicates in column D, the dictionary will only contain/return the row number of the FIRST instance/match
        For rowIndex = LBound(columnD, 1) To UBound(columnD, 1)
            If Not dict.Exists(columnD(rowIndex, 1)) Then
                dict.Add columnD(rowIndex, 1), rowIndex
            End If
        Next rowIndex

        Dim outputArray() As Variant
        ReDim outputArray(1 To READ_ROW_COUNT, 1 To 1)
        Dim rowIndexOfFirstMatch As Long

        ' Now loop through column A's values and check if it exists in dict
        For rowIndex = LBound(columnA, 1) To UBound(columnA, 1)
            If dict.Exists(columnA(rowIndex, 1)) Then
                rowIndexOfFirstMatch = dict.Item(columnA(rowIndex, 1))
                outputArray(rowIndex, 1) = columnE(rowIndexOfFirstMatch, 1)
            Else
                outputArray(rowIndex, 1) = "#N/A" ' Change to zero if needed.
            End If
        Next rowIndex

        .Range("B1").Resize(READ_ROW_COUNT, 1) = outputArray

    End With
End Sub
```

I tested the code on some dummy data that I generated on my end and to me it seems like the code should do what you've described (for each value in column A, column B in my output contains either `#N/A` or the value in column E if a match was found). If it still doesn't, let me know why/what's wrong.

Comment: I have tried your code, but the **resize function** is killing me. It doesn't work, because it copies exactly the same values as the second incomplete list of time values.  I have 2 different time arrays (column 1 and 4), column 1 contains each time value of the year 2017 per hour (2017010101, read as yyyymmddhr), and another time array which doesnt contain all hourly values (e.g. 2017010101, then insteadof 2017010102 -it jumps to 2017010105).

Comment: In my solution, the temperature values at 2017010103 and 2017010104 should be cero values or #NA. I tried to change this line: `inputArray = .range("E1").resize(NUMBER_OF_ROWS_TO_COMPARE, 1).value2` but it does the same. Is there another function to match instead of resize?

Comment: @levellingup You want to check if each value in column A exists in column D. If it does exist, you want to copy the value from column E (of the matching row) to column B (same row as value in column A) -- and if it doesn't exist, you want to put a `0` or `#N/A`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @levellingup Have edited and rewritten my answer, if you want to try again.

Comment: It's working super now. I checked the problem before  with **Resize** was that  were reading from column A to E (1 to 5) `inputArray = .Range("A1").Resize(NUMBER_OF_ROWS_TO_COMPARE, 5).Value2`, the code was restricting the number of rows to the shortest one (timearray2-6929: column D instead of timearray1-10,000:column A). Now that each array is declared separately, it runs ok. And also now you changed outputarray as a dynamic array. Thankss!

Answer (score 0):

Consider SQL if using Excel for PC as the Office application can interface to the JET/ACE SQL Engine (Windows .DLL files). Essentially, you need a conditional calculation across columns which can be handled with [`IIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) (counterpart to ANSI SQL's `CASE`). For this set-based operation, 10,000 records is very quick to run. No loops needed for this solution.

Below assumes:

1. You run Excel 2007+ on PC with ODBC/OLEDB drivers installed.
2. Data begins at `A1` with named columns. Ranges and fields can be changed as needed. Adjust columns and sheet name in SQL, leaving brackets `[]` and `$`)
3. An empty sheet named "RESULTS" exists.

**SQL** *(embedded in VBA)*

```sql
SELECT t.*, IIF(t.[TimeValue1] = t.[TimeValue2], t.[TemperatureValue], 0) As NewColumn
FROM [SheetName$] t
```

**VBA**

```vb
Sub RunSQL()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer, fld As Object

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' ODBC AND OLEDB CONNECTIONS
    '    strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
    '                      & "DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";"
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                       & "Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';" _
                       & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;"";"

    strSQL = "SELECT t.*, IIF(t.timeValue1 = t.timeValue2, t.Temperaturevalue, 0) As NewColumn" _
             & " FROM [SheetName$] t;"

    ' OPEN CONNECTION
    conn.Open strConnection
    rst.Open strSQL, conn

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RESULTS")
       ' COLUMNS
       For i = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
          .Cells(1, i) = rst.Fields(i - 1).Name
       Next i 

       ' DATA
      .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
    End With

    rst.Close: conn.Close
    MsgBox "Successfully ran SQL query!", vbInformation

ExitHandle:
    Set rst = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
    Resume ExitHandle
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried also your code, changed all the names, it runs but it doesn't work either, because when it detects the difference between one and the other arrays of time, it just sets zero from then on (e.g. correct values up tpp 2017020210, 2017020212 doesn't exist in time array 2, then it puts zero, but then from 2017020212 to 2017123123 it assigns zero, even though there are of course several other temperature values). Does IIF works with an else?

Comment: SQL is a set based language so runs across rows and columns in tabular (i.e., sets) arrangement. It does not look at subsequent rows or back. But I am not understanding since `2017020212` does not equal `2017123123` so it should be assigned zero. `IIF` third argument is the else condition. You can even nest it. See docs linked in this answer. It would help to see your initial data and these undesired results.

Comment: my data is this: from cell (A1) to (A10000): time sequence per hour: (2017010101, 2017010102, 2017010103... etc), column "B" is where I want to paste temp. values. Column "D" is raw data where a thermometer sometimes couldn't register the temperature at each hour (e.g. 2017010101, 2017010102, 2017010106, etc.). What your code is doing: copying until there is a gap, in the example it would copy the first 2 temperatures ok, but then from 2017010103 until the last period, it would all be zero regardless if there is more data after the gap (e.g starting reading the values from 2017010106 & so on).

Comment: Please edit your post with cleaner view of data. Comments are hard to read. But it appears you already have a solution! Good luck and happy coding!